# How do you statically link Rust and C sources that depend on each other through FFI?

Tags: c, rust, static-linking, ffi

What is the minimal Makefile or `cargo`/`rustc` + `cc` invocation to statically link Rust and C sources that depend on each other? Something like this (adapted from [alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples/tree/master/c-to-rust/src)), which is similar to the [example in the Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#targeting-callbacks-to-rust-objects):

main.c

```c
struct contrived { double x; double y; }

double GLOBAL_CONSTANT = 100;

extern double consume_input(struct contrived input);

int main() {
    double output = consume_input({.x = 1, .y = 2});
    printf("Got %f.", output);
    return 0;
}
```

lib.rs

```
#![crate_type = "staticlib"]

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Contrived {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

extern {
    #[link(name = "main", kind = "static")]
    static GLOBAL_CONSTANT: f64;
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn consume_input(input: Contrived) -> f64 {
    input.x - input.y + GLOBAL_CONSTANT
}
```

If lib.rs only depended on the struct, does it not actually depend on the C lib?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What have you *already tried*? There are [entire sites](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/) dedicated to calling Rust code from other languages (including C) with working examples. Saying things like "the C lib" adds confusion because there *are no C libraries* in your question; presumably the file called "main" will be compiled into an executable (maybe through an object first).

Answer (score 0):

This is no different than the ['c-to-rust' example](https://github.com/alexcrichton/rust-ffi-examples/tree/master/c-to-rust).

This was me not understanding the distinction between the compiling and linking stages; the Rust file's dependency on `GLOBAL_CONSTANT` is not resolved until link time, so there is no problem with creating `librust.a` then later linking it with the executable.